# Passing data between controllers - unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional

Tags: ios, swift, null

I am attempting a very simple task of passing data between two view controllers. I have control-dragged the label into the proper class and allowed the segues to populate with the correct data. Upon clicking the row, the `prepareForSegue` action is as:

```
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "individualChat" {
            if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {

                let friend: Friend

                friend = mappedFriends[indexPath.row]

                let controller = segue.destinationViewController as! IndividualChatController

                controller.friendChat = friend

            }
        }
   }
```

and into the residing view controller:

```
import UIKit

class IndividualChatController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var anotherTestLabel: UILabel!

    var friendChat: Friend! {
        didSet {
            configureView()
        }
    }

    func configureView() {
        if let friendChat = friendChat {

            anotherTestLabel.text = friendChat.name as? String

        }
    }
}
```

Yet, upon clicking the row, the error appears:

`fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

on line:

`anotherTestLabel.text = friendChat.name as? String`

How can this be fixed?

*Additional Screen Capture:*

[image]

Comment: yes it is connected, see the screen capture added

Comment: check if friendChat.name isn't nil

Comment: it isn't I can `print` to view data...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you execute some code in `prepareForSegue` the next view is not loaded yet so all your outlets are still set to `nil`; because of this when you try to implicitly unwrap the content of `anotherTestLabel` at

```
anotherTestLabel.text = friendChat.name as? String
```

you get that error.

You can check if your label has been loaded and only if that's the case set its text using

```
anotherTestLabel?.text = friendChat.name as? String
```

and then manually calling `configureView()` in `viewDidLoad()` of `IndividualChatController` to proper load the label.

The added `?` will check if your label is `nil`, if so nothing will be done, else it will proceed unwrapping the label and setting the text.

Comment: Yes, this was exactly it. I did away with the `configureView`, and simply allowed setting within `viewDidLoad`, and everything is fine